# Configure remote-user name in Wildfly OIDC

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, openid-connect

I successfully configured Wildfly 26 to authenticate via Keycloak following the usual tutorial. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gQO4_7Z5CI

It works as announced - when required the user's browser gets redirected to keycloak, after login it redirects back. That much for authentication. I also checked that the authorization can be performed by running `request.isUserInRole(...)` which is true if and only if in keycloak some role was associated to that user. That much for authorization.

But the methods `request.getRemoteUser()` and `request.getUserPrincipal().getName()` only return the keycloak's userid, which looks like  `896128e8-3260-42c8-9457-3c8ee236eb4d`.

How can I make Wildfly OIDC to report the username by looking at the preferred_username token claim?

Answer (score 1):

So I learned that Wildfly's OIDC client can be configured to read the principal name from another token claim. For this it was sufficient to add the line

```
"principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
```

into my web application's WEB-INF/oidc.json. This is the only line required on top of the configuration generated by Keycloak:

```
{
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
  "realm" : "myrealm",
  "auth-server-url" : "http://localhost:8180/",
  "ssl-required" : "external",
  "resource" : "webapp",
  "credentials" : {
    "secret" : "7BqGXjt7cw6p88DNoiXCi1663bIzKPwY"
  },
  "confidential-port" : 0
}
```

When authenticating, the tokens emitted by Keycloak are exactly the same however the client uses the specified field's value instead of the `sub` value.

From the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_java_adapter_config):

***principal-attribute***

*OpenID Connect ID Token attribute to populate the UserPrincipal name with. If token attribute is null, defaults to sub. Possible values are sub, preferred_username, email, name, nickname, given_name, family_name.*